# Clear chrome browser history programmatically

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-browser

I have tried using the following code but it doesn't work with chrome, only the old browser.

```
Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());
```

Comment: Note that `Browser` was eliminated entirely in API Level 23.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you know if there's anyway to interact with the chrome browser?

Comment: Nothing in the Android SDK itself. Whether the Chrome team has documented any sort of API for their Android app, I cannot say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code work for me

```
private void clearHistoryChrome() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    if (canClearHistory(cr)) {
        deleteHistoryWhere(cr, null);
    }
}

private void deleteHistoryWhere(ContentResolver cr, String whereClause) {
    String CONTENT_URI = "content://com.android.chrome.browser/history";
    Uri URI = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI);
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = cr.query(URI, new String[]{"url"}, whereClause,
                null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final WebIconDatabase iconDb = WebIconDatabase.getInstance();
                do {
                    // Delete favicons
                    // TODO don't release if the URL is bookmarked
                    iconDb.releaseIconForPageUrl(cursor.getString(0));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cr.delete(URI, whereClause, null);
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.i("DEBUG_", "deleteHistoryWhere IllegalStateException: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) cursor.close();
    }
    Log.i("DEBUG_", "deleteHistoryWhere: GOOD");
}

public boolean canClearHistory(ContentResolver cr) {
    String CONTENT_URI = "content://com.android.chrome.browser/history";
    Uri URI = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI);
    String _ID = "_id";
    String VISITS = "visits";
    Cursor cursor = null;
    boolean ret = false;
    try {
        cursor = cr.query(URI,
                new String[]{_ID, VISITS},
                null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            ret = cursor.getCount() > 0;
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.i("DEBUG_", "canClearHistory IllegalStateException: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) cursor.close();
    }
    Log.i("DEBUG_", "canClearHistory: " + ret);
    return ret;
}
```

I think this will help you

Comment: canClearHistory log value get false what can i do?

Comment: Log.i("DEBUG_", "canClearHistory: " + ret);
    return ret;